# JS-generated GET variables not being read PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am using JavaScript to generate a form's `action` attribute:

```
$("#select-font").on('change', function(){
    var font = $(this).val();
    $("#font-family").val(font);
    $(this).css({
      'font-family': font
    });
    $("#edit-doc").css({
      'font-family': font
    });
    // BUG IS HERE --->
    $('#save')
        .attr('src', '/img/icons2/save.png')
        .attr('onclick', '$(this).parents("form").submit();');
    $('#save')
        .parents('form')
        .attr('action', 
            String($('#save')
                .parents('form')
                .attr('action')) + '&autosave=true');
    });
    $("#select-font-size")
        .on('change', function(){
            var size = $(this).val();
            $("#edit-doc").css({
                'font-size': size
            });
            $("#font-size").val(size);
            // BUG IS HERE --->
            $('#save')
                .attr('src', '/img/icons2/save.png')
                .attr('onclick', 
                    '$(this).parents("form").submit();');
            $('#save')
                .parents('form')
                .attr('action',   
                    String($('#save')
                        .parents('form')
                        .attr('action')) + '&autosave=true');
        });
```

The GET variable is passed to the next page; in the URL bar the location shows up as `http://localhost/foo/?var1=a&var2=b&autosave=true`. However, when I test the GET variable:

```
if($_GET["autosave"]){
   // some code...
}
```

The condition is not run. Why can't the PHP see the variable?

Comment: Check the received URL first on the PHP side

Comment: Well I used `print_r` on the GET array, it gave me: `Array ( [var1] => a [var2] => b [autosave] => )`, so the value is not being passed, but the actual variable is being made.

Comment: Then check on JS side whether it is correctly passed

Comment: Okay, I noticed a small glitch in the code, but it shouldn't affect the program's running, I did `console.log()` and it showed up the `autosave` value being `true`.

Comment: Now did u get the value in the PHP side?

Comment: Yes, I used `print_r` on it.

Comment: Using the 'onclick' attribute instead of jquery.on('click',function(){}); is not ideal to say the least. Also your code is badly chained and not closed... at least not in the snippet here.

Comment: Found the problem, I was blocking the variable by default right at the top of the file, its fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using

```
if($_GET["autosave"]){
    // some code...
}
```

try:

```
if (isset($_GET["autosave"])) {
    // your code...
}
```

Also when adding handlers try this, rather than using the inline click handler, use [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('#save')
    .attr('src', '/img/icons2/save.png')
    .on('click', function(){
         $(this).parents("form").submit();
    });
```